# when i tried to execute this procedure it gives me an error, invalid object

Tags: plsql

When I tried to execute this procedure it gives me an error, invalid object ora-06550 error.

What should I do ?

This procedure insert values into some tables and do some calculation.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT(P_ENTRY_DATE DATE) AS
      L_COUNT          NUMBER(10) := 0;
      l_party_count    number(10) := 0;
      L_NET_AMOUNT     NUMBER(10);
      L_COUNT1         NUMBER(10) := 0;
      L_GEN_VOUCHER_NO VARCHAR(20);
      L_PAYMENT_ID     NUMBER(10);
      L_PARTY_ID       NUMBER(10) := 0;
      L_CO6_NO         VARCHAR2(10) := 0;
      l_max_party_code NUMBER(10);
      L_NAME           VARCHAR2(100);
      CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT NAME, AMOUNT
          FROM TMP_SCHOLARSHIP_DATA
         WHERE ENTRY_DATE LIKE P_ENTRY_DATE;
      CURSOR C_NAME IS
        SELECT NAME
          FROM TMP_SCHOLARSHIP_DATA
         WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT PARTY_NAME
                              FROM M_FIS_PARTY
                             WHERE SCHOLARSHIP_FLAG = 'S'
                               AND DELETE_FLAG = 'N')
           AND ENTRY_DATE = P_ENTRY_DATE;
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO L_COUNT
        FROM TMP_SCHOLARSHIP_DATA
       WHERE ENTRY_DATE LIKE P_ENTRY_DATE;




     -- L_CO6_NO := P_CO6_NO;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STARTING CO6 NO=======' || L_CO6_NO);
      select max(TO_NUMBER(party_code)) + 1
        into l_max_party_code
        from m_fis_party;
      FOR I IN C_NAME LOOP
        L_PARTY_ID := SFN_ADM_GENERATE_SEQNO('M_FIS_PARTY', 'FIS');
        INSERT INTO M_FIS_PARTY
          (PARTY_ID,
           PARTY_CODE,
           PARTY_NAME,
           DELETE_FLAG,
           CREATED_BY,
           CREATION_DATE,
           SCHOLARSHIP_FLAG,
           PARTY_TYPE_OTH_CODE,
           PARTY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
           BANK_NAME,
           IFSC_CODE)
        VALUES
          (L_PARTY_ID,
           TO_CHAR(l_max_party_code),
           I.NAME,
           'N',
           'FISDEV',
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE),
           'S',
           'SCHOLARSHIP',
           I.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
           I.BANK_NAME,
           I.IFSC_CODE);
        L_MAX_PARTY_CODE := L_MAX_PARTY_CODE + 1;
        l_party_count    := l_party_count + 1;
      END LOOP;
      FOR REC_C1 IN C1 LOOP
        L_PAYMENT_ID     := SFN_ADM_GENERATE_SEQNO('T_FIS_PAYMENT_HDR', 'FIS');
        l_gen_voucher_no := SFN_FIS_Generate_VoucherNumber('PAYORDER',
                                                           'A',
                                                           'D',
                                                           SYSDATE);
        SELECT PARTY_ID
          INTO L_PARTY_ID
          FROM M_FIS_PARTY
         WHERE PARTY_NAME = REC_C1.NAME
           AND SCHOLARSHIP_FLAG = 'S';

           SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(CLASSIF_ORD_NO))+1 INTO L_CO6_NO
           FROM T_FIS_PAYMENT_HDR;




          -- AND ROWNUM < 2;
        L_NET_AMOUNT := 0;
        IF (REC_C1.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL) THEN
          L_NET_AMOUNT := REC_C1.AMOUNT;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO T_FIS_PAYMENT_HDR
          (PAYMENT_ID,
           PAYMENT_NO,
           PAY_ORD_DATE,
           PAYMENT_TYPE_ID,
           PAYEE_TYPE_ID,
           PAYEE_ID,
           PAID_TO_NAME,
           NET_AMOUNT,
           PAYMENT_STATUS,
           APPROVAL_FLAG,
           POST_FLAG,
           DELETE_FLAG,
           CREATED_BY,
           CREATION_DATE,
           PAY_ORD_NO,
           SCHOLARSHIP_FLAG,
           REMARKS,
           PRINT_FLAG,
           DOCUMENT_NO,
           FIS_SECTION,
           CLASSIF_ORD_NO,
           DEPT_PAYORDER_NO,
           CLASSIF_ORD_DATE,
           SUB_SECTION_CODE,
           DEPT_PAYORDER_DATE)
        VALUES
          (L_PAYMENT_ID,
           L_GEN_VOUCHER_NO,
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE),
           3,
           3,
           L_PARTY_ID,
           REC_C1.NAME,
           L_NET_AMOUNT,
           'U',
           'N',
           'N',
           'N',
           'FISDEV',
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE),
           L_GEN_VOUCHER_NO,
           'S',
           'SCHOLARSHIP 2016-2017',
           'N',
           '878-',
           'A',
           L_CO6_NO,
           'CC0080842',
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE),
           'HQXP',
           '05-MAR-15');
        INSERT INTO T_FIS_PAYMENT_DTL
          (PAYMENT_ID,
           LINE_NO,
           COMBINATION_ID,
           AMOUNT,
           DEBIT_CREDIT_FLAG,
           DELETE_FLAG,
           CREATED_BY,
           CREATION_DATE,
           REMARKS)
        VALUES
          (L_PAYMENT_ID,
           1,
           '16287',
           L_NET_AMOUNT,
           'D',
           'N',
           'FISDEV',
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE),
           'SCHOLARSHIP 2016-2017');
        L_COUNT1   := L_COUNT1 + 1;
        L_PARTY_ID := L_PARTY_ID + 1;
        L_CO6_NO   := L_CO6_NO + 1;
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL PARTY INSERTED======' || l_party_count);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL SELECTED======' || L_COUNT);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL INSERTED======' || L_COUNT1);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST PAYMENT_NO===' || L_GEN_VOUCHER_NO);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST PAYMENT_ID===' || L_PAYMENT_ID);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST PARTY_ID===' || L_PARTY_ID);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LAST CO6 NO===' || L_CO6_NO);
    END;

    **Here the error what shows when i tried to execute this procedure.**

    SQL> exec SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT('14-feb-2017');
    begin SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT('14-feb-2017'); end;
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PLS-00905: object FIS.SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT is invalid
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: when you compile the SP, do you see any errors why this SP is invalid?

Comment: no its compiled fine.

Comment: It cannot be possible that your code would had compiled properly. Error clearly says that object is invalid

Comment: The error stack clearly says `PLS-00905: object FIS.SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT is invalid`. Your anonymous block fails when trying to call it because it's invalid. What is the output of `show errors procedure spr_fis_scholarship_insert`? btw it takes a date parameter but you're passing a string.

Answer (score 0):

`ora-06550 error`. This error comes when you try to execute an invalid block of PLSQL code (like a stored procedure or function), but a compilation error occurred.

So your code is not properly compiled. You can do `show error` to check the error in `SQLPLUS`.

When you use clients like `Toad` or `PLSQL developer` and try to comiple a stored proc, it gives `message PLSQL block compiled with error` which doesnot mean it compiled properly.

Comment: the stored procedure compiled fine it has no error.

Comment: Check if all the tables you are using in the procedure are present.

Comment: all tables are present.

Comment: Post all your table DDL then. Let me check once. Also is the procedure you are using inside is valid ? Have you checked that.

Comment: tmp_scholarship_data       ----------------------------------------------------------             student_name varchar2(100) y  
bank_name varchar2(100) y  
bank_acc_number varchar2(100) y  
ifsc_code varchar2(20) y  
amount number(20,2) y  
entry_date date y

Comment: Post it in your question. All the table DDL not just one.

Comment: Cursors `c1` and `c_name` try to select name from tmp_scholarship_data, but in the comment above it seems tmp_scholarship_data has a `student_name` column, not `name`.

Comment: The loop beginning `for i in c_name loop` refers to `i.name`, `i.bank_account_number`, `i.bank_name` and `i.ifsc_code` but cursor `c_name` only has `student_name`.

Comment: You insert the string `'05-MAR-15'` into `dept_payorder_date`, but presumably it should be a date like `date '2015-03-05'`. Also the code uses `to_date(sysdate)` in five places, which I'm guessing was meant to be `trunc(sysdate)`. However these are runtime issues not compilation errors.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. Please post all your comments under OP question. He would then have access.

Comment: @XING good point. It was OP#s the comment posting DDL for tmp_scholarship_data that got me started ;)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson.. Take your time..Consolidate your thoughts and then post a single comments rather than posting your view many times increasing the  number of comments unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Hang on..

```
 L_CO6_NO         VARCHAR2(10) := 0;
```

That should give an error, possibly at run time if not at compile time. That could be it.

Comment: That's correct catch Andrew. I guess OP doesnot know if his code is compiling or not.

Comment: No it won't. The number will get implicitly converted to a string, which may or may not cause problems, and I agree it's poor practice, but it won't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure really does have compilation errors, as stated in your original error stack:

```
SQL> exec SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT('14-feb-2017');
begin SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT('14-feb-2017'); end;
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object FIS.SPR_FIS_SCHOLARSHIP_INSERT is invalid
```

Use the following command in SQL*Plus or equivalent to display the errors:

```
show errors procedure spr_fis_scholarship_insert
```

Cursors `c1` and `c_name` select name from tmp_scholarship_data, but in one of your comments it seems the table seems only has a `student_name` column, not `name`.

The loop beginning `for i in c_name loop` refers to `i.name`, `i.bank_account_number`, `i.bank_name` and `i.ifsc_code` but cursor c_name only has `student_name`.

You insert the string `'05-MAR-15'` into dept_payorder_date, and pass `'14-feb-2017'` as `p_entry_date`, but presumably they should be dates like `date '2015-03-05'` and `date '2017-02-14'`. Also the code uses `to_date(sysdate)` in several places, which I'm guessing was meant to be `trunc(sysdate)`. However these are runtime issues not compilation errors.

There may be other issues but I don't have definitions for M_FIS_PARTY, T_FIS_PAYMENT_HDR and T_FIS_PAYMENT_DTL. (I can create dummy functions for sfn_adm_generate_seqno and sfn_fis_generate_vouchernumber. btw why aren't all these in a package?)